# S-matrix for the HOMFLY/Hecke category

Tags: reference-request, quantum-topology, topological-quantum-field-theory, rt.representation-theory

This question concerns the HOMFLY-PT category, closely related to Hecke algebras.  (See [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9702017.pdf) for example.)

The minimal idempotents of this category are indexed by pairs $(\lambda_+, \lambda_-)$ of Young diagrams. (The sizes of the diagrams are arbitrary and need not be the same.  The diagram $\lambda_+$ corresponds to upward oriented strands, while $\lambda_-$ corresponds to downward oriented strands.) Consequently one can define numerical invariants of oriented links whose components are labeled by pairs of Young diagrams.  This is the "colored" HOMFLY-PT polynomial.

Of fundamental importance in this subject are the invariants $S_{\lambda_+\lambda_-,\mu_+\mu_-}$ of the [Hopf link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100881/s-matrix-for-the-bmw-category) with its components labeled by pairs of Young diagrams (i.e. idempotents) $(\lambda_+, \lambda_-)$ and $(\mu_+, \mu_-)$.  In TQFT language, this is the "S-matrix" of the theory.

My Question:

> Has the S-matrix for the HOMFLY-PT category been calculated and published?  If not, are partial results in this direction known?

I am aware of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math.GT/0108011.pdf) by Morton and Lukac, which does the case where $\lambda_-$ and $\mu_-$ are both empty (i.e. all strands oriented the same direction).  [This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math.GT/0106207.pdf) by Morton and Hadji is also related.  Are there other relevant papers that I have missed?

See also the BMW version of this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100881/s-matrix-for-the-bmw-category).

Comment: I'm a little late to the party. Not sure if I've understood what you're looking for, but for a simple object $q$ in a UMTC whose fusion spaces induce representations of the Hecke algebra, we get $\tilde{S}_{qq}=\varkappa_{q}d_{q}\left[r_{1}^{*}(r_{1}+r_{2})-r_{1}r_{2}\left(\frac{r_{1}^{*}+r_{1}^{2}r_{2}}{r_{1}+r_{2}}\right)\right]$, where $\tilde{S}$ is the unnormalised $S$-matrix, $\varkappa_{q}$ is the $\pm1$ Frobenius-Schur indicator, $d_{q}$ the quantum dimension, and $r_{1}$ & $r_{2}$ the eigenvalues of the $R$-matrix $R_{qq}$.

Comment: Also, $d_{q}$ can be expressed in terms of $\varkappa_{q}, r_{1}, r_{2}$, so that formula can be simplified or expanded.

Answer (score 4):

The $S$-matrix is given by 
\begin{equation}
\frac{S_{ij}}{S_{00}}=S_{R_i}(q^{\rho})S_{R_j}(q^{\rho+R_i})
\end{equation}
where $S_{R}(x_1,\cdots,x_N)$ is the Schur polynomial with highest weight $R$, $S_{R}(q^{\rho})=S_{R}(q^{\rho_{1}},...,q^{\rho_{N}})$ and $\rho$ is the Weyl vector. 
Furthermore, the [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.5117) by Aganagic and Shakirov propoesed the refinement (categorification) of the $S$-matrix
\begin{equation}
\frac{S_{ij}}{S_{00}}=M_{R_i}(t^{\rho})M_{R_j}(t^{\rho}q^{R_i})
\end{equation}
where $M_{R}(x_1,\cdots,x_N;q,t)$ is the Macdonald polynomial with highest weight $R$ and $M_{R}(t^{\rho}q^{R})=M_{R}(t^{\rho_{1}}q^{R_{1}},...,t^{\rho_{N}}q^{R_{n}};q,t)$. It reduces to the above equation for $q=t$. By using the refined topological vertex, Iqbal and Kozcaz showed that the Khovanov-Rozansky polynomial of the Hopf link is actually proportional to the refined $S$-matrix
\begin{equation}
KhR_{ij}({\rm Hopf},q,t)\propto M_{R_i}(t^{\rho})M_{R_j}(t^{\rho}q^{R_i})
\end{equation}
See Eq.(4.10) and appendix B in the [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0525v1).

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, these formulas are for the case where all strands are oriented in the same direction.  (i.e. the case where $\mu_-$ and $\lambda_-$ of the question are both empty.)  This case is also covered in the Morton and Lukac paper I refer to above.  But it's nice to know about other papers discussing other viewpoints, so thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did not understand your question correctly. But, that's all I know.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete answer, but it might make some partial progress. First I'll slightly restate the question. If we decompose $S^3$ into two solid tori and write $C$ and $C^{op}$ for the Homfly skein modules of these tori, then there is a pairing $$\langle -,-\rangle: C\otimes_A C^{op} \to k$$
where $k$ is the base ring (which is isomorphic to the skein module of $S^3$) and $A$ is the Homfly skein algebra of the torus. As you say, both $C$ and $C^{op}$ have bases indexed by pairs of partitions, and if I understand right, the entries of the $S$ matrix are evaluations of this pairing.

One brute-force approach for computing $\langle (\lambda, \mu), (\lambda',\mu')\rangle$ is to "move the left hand side to the right using the action of $A$ and then evaluate." An explicit presentation of $A$ is given here http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0859. There are generators $P(a,b)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb(Z)$ (which are "the $gcd(a,b)$ power sum on slope $b/a$"), and they satisfy the commutation relations $$[P(x), P(y)] = (q^d-q^{-d}) P(x+y),\quad x,y \in \mathbb Z^2,\quad d = det[x\,\,y]$$
(If $x$ and $y$ are primitive and $d=1$ this is just the skein relation.) The paper also gives explicit formulas for the action of the generators $P(a,b)$ in the basis $(\lambda,\mu)$ that you mentioned, and these formulas actually aren't too bad (e.g. if $a,b \not= 0$ then the entries in the matrix are monomials).

One difficulty in completing the answer is that expressing the basis elements $(\lambda,\mu)$ in terms of power sums isn't too easy. (Morton does have a determinental formulas in terms of complete symmetric functions in one of his papers.) Also, I'm not sure if the evaluations $((\emptyset, \emptyset),(\lambda,\mu)\rangle$ have actually been computed.

(By the way, this algebra $A$ actually has a lot of different realization which are not obviously the same. One other realization is as (a specialization of) the Hall algebra of coherent sheaves on an elliptic curve over a finite field (this is described in the paper above). Also, if you've found these numbers since the question was asked I'd be curious to hear.)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have a look at the paper you refer to.  In answer to your final remark, no, I have not not learned anything new about this since asking the question.